# OpenStreetMap other maps

Tags: dictionary, openstreetmap

Can anyone tell me why the `Swedish OpenStreetMap` looks much better than the one that can be found at `OpenStreetMap.org` And is there a way to include the `Swedish` one in my application without connecting to Swedish servers?

Comment: What do you mean by _better_? It would be better to add links to the maps you want to be compared. I assume that the basic data is the same, so probably the styling is different. If you use a WMS you won't be able to change the styling much. If you use WFS or server the data yourself you can of course change the styling of the map completely.

Comment: The official style is supposed to look detailed for mappers not for end users